# How to Upload application in ios for Build

Tags: app-store-connect

I am new in iOS and I want to upload my app in iTunes Connect. I have done all steps for uploading but when I upload in iTunes Connect it validate and upload sucessfully in App Store but its not showing it in Activity Build.

Answer (score 0):

Use Application Loader for uploading. There is an issue with xcode sometimes when we minimize that uploading window, it quickly shows that build uploaded successfully. To avoid this, use Application Loader.